# Read Input on same line as another Read Input

Tags: c#

First off, this question IS NOT

```
System.Console.Write instead of System.Console.WriteLine
....
<Console.Write();>: <Console.ReadLine>
```

I think this best explains my question,

I have...

```
string stringone = Console.ReadLine();
string stringtwo = Console.ReadLine();

....

//what it does

<Console.ReadLine> (after enter is pressed moves to next line)
<Console.ReadLine>

//what I want

<Console.ReadLine> <Console.ReadLine>
```

Any alternative/solution or grounds if this is possible is greatly apreciated.

Comment: Why not put both strings seperated by a space on the same line then split em after ?

Comment: Do you just want to read two strings on the same line?

Comment: Yes I want to read two strings on the same line

Comment: Then separate them with a character. Something like "space" or comma

Comment: throws System.FormatException

Comment: Simple solution is to use a `string` array to store all space separated strings from the input. `string[] strings = Console.WriteLine().Split()`. Index the array to get what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
using System;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        //split input by spaces into array
        string[] name = Console.ReadLine().Split(); 
        Console.WriteLine("First name: " + name[0]);
        Console.WriteLine("Last Name: " + name[1]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use SetCursorPosition.

```
using System;

class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string question1 = "What is your name? ";
        string question2 = "How old are you? ";

        // first question
        Console.Write(question1);
        string name = Console.ReadLine();

        // second question
        Console.SetCursorPosition(question1.Length + name.Length + 1, 0);
        Console.Write(question2);
        string age = Console.ReadLine();

        // print output
        Console.WriteLine("Hello {0}, your age is {1}", name, age);

        Console.Write("Press any key to continue . . . ");
        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }
}
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.setcursorposition(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Seems like an awful lot of trouble for something that seems simple... Thanks anyways

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
string one = Console.ReadLine();
Console.SetCursorPosition(one.Length + 1, 0);
string two = Console.ReadLine();
Console.SetCursorPosition(one.Length + two.Length + 2, 0);
```